# Missing HttpOnly Attribute for Session Identifier with HTTP protocol

Tags: java, servlets, session-cookies, httponly, cookie-httponly

Earlier I was getting HttpOnly for both HTTP/HTTPS protocol, but missing secure attribute.

In order to add "Secure" attribute, I added secure="true" in server.xml ’s Connector port syntax as below –

```
<Connector address="10.23.17.69" port="8000" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="60000" disableUploadTimeout="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8"  server="Dev" secure="true" />
```

Also added "cookie-config" in web.xml as below –

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <secure>true</secure>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Now for HTTPS protocol, I’m getting ‘Secure’ and ‘HttpOnly’ flags as true for Session cookie as below.

But for HTTP protocol, I'm not getting HttpOnly attribute. I need "HttpOnly=true" in case of HTTP protocol.

Please note, my context.xml's "Context" element already contains useHttpOnly attribute as following -

```
<Context useHttpOnly="true">
 ....
</Context>
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/338313) I think you have incorrectly set the session cookies attribute.

It should be:

```
<Context cookies="true" crossContext="true">
  <SessionCookie secure="true" httpOnly="true" />
```